# Extracting a List of Decimal numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a textarea that will have one or more pairings that look like this,

```
Lat = 38.7970308 
Long = -100.8665928
```

How can I extract the numbers using Javascript (negative sign included if there)?  I want all the numbers listed.

Comment: Could you provide the code you have tried?

Comment: using javascript regex match i used ^[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$ a modified version of a similar question

Comment: @kitkatCodes: are numbers with formats like `.12345` or `12345.` or `000123` or `123.00` or `-0.0` allowed?

Comment: No a leading or trailing 0 would be required for the first 2 the 3rd is fine as it doesn't effect the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
var s ='Lat = 38.7970308\n' + 
'Long = -100.8665928';

var m = s.match(/[+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+)/g);
//=> ["38.7970308", "-100.8665928"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
[\+\-]?\d+.?\d+$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/([+-]?(?:[0-9]+\.)?[0-9]+)/g
```

**http://regex101.com/r/mC0yO2/1**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern to basically extract all the numbers:

```
/-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g
```

If, as in your string example, you want to extract these numbers by pairs, you need to use capturing groups:

```
/^Lat = (-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*?\r?\nLong = (-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*?$/mg
```

for each pairs founded, the latitude is in the capture group 1 and the longitude in the capture group 2.

Note that this second pattern take in account that literal strings "Lat = " and "Long = " are at the start of a line, always in this order, and only separated by a newline character. *(with the m modifier, `^` means "start of the line, and `$` means "end of the line")*. Trailing spaces are allowed with `\s*?` for each line.

Example:

```
var yourString = "Lat = 38.7970308\nLong = -100.8665928";
var myRe = /^Lat = (-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*?\r?\nLong = (-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*?$/mg;
var m;

while ((m = myRe.exec(yourString)) !== null) {
  console.log(m[1] + "\t" + m[2]+ "\n\n");
}
```